# Laravel php Registering and logging in new user

Tags: php, laravel

Using the laravel framework and eclipse mars to write my code.  I am having issues with creating a new user and add that user into my SQL Server users table. The error I get when signing a new user up is - Error loading page.

app\Http\routes.php

```
<?php
/*
   |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
   | Application Routes
   |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |
   | Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
   | It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
   | and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
   |
*/

/*Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});*/
Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index');

Route::get('product', 'WelcomeController@product');
//Route::controller('WelcomeController');

Route::get("home", function(){return view('welcome');});
Route::get("products", 'ProductController@products');
Route::get("product/{id}", 'ProductController@product');
//Route::get('product/{id}', function ($id) {
//  return $id;
//});
Route::get("orders", 'OrderController@orders');
Route::get("order/{id}", 'OrderController@order');
Route::get("rssfeed", 'RssFeedController@rssfeed');

// Authentication routes...
Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');

// Registration routes...
Route::get('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
Route::post('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');
```

resources\views\auth\register.blade.php

```
   @extends('master.master') 

   @section('content')
   <div id='register'>
     <form method="post" action='auth/register'>
       {!! csrf_field() !!}

        <div id='emailBox'>
           <label for='email'>Email:</label> <input name='email' id='email'
            type='email' value="{{ old('email') }}" />
       </div>
       <div id='passBox'>
           <label for='password'>Password</label> <input name='password'
               id='password' type='password' />
       </div>


       <div id='nameBox'>
           <label for='name'>First Name:</label> <input name='name' id='name'
               type='text'>
       </div>

       <div id='signUpBox'>
           <input type="submit" value="Sign Up!" id='signUpButton' class='cloudButton'>
       </div>
   </form>
</div>
@stop
```

resources\views\auth\login.blade.php

```
@extends('master.master')

@section('content')
<div id='login-form'>
<form method="POST" action="/auth/login">
   {!! csrf_field() !!}

   <div id='emailBox'>
       <label for='email'>Email:</label>
       <input name='email' id='email' type='email' value="{{old('email') }}"/>
   </div>
   <div id='passBox'>
       <label for='password'>Password</label>
       <input name='password' id='password' type='password' />
   </div>

   <div id='rememberBox'>
       <label for='remember'>Remember Me!</label>
       <input name='remember' id='remember' type='checkbox' />
   </div>
   <div id='loginBox'>
           <input type="submit" value="Log In!" id='loginButton' class='cloudButton'>
   </div>
</form>
```

@stop

app\User.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword;

/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'Users';

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password'];

/**
 * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];
public function user(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\OrderHeader', 'UserID', 'id');
}
}
```

Comment: Which Laravel version do you use? Is it an option for you to upgrade to the latest version (it has new auth)? What is the full error message?

Comment: Not a lot of info in the error message you posted, should be able to find more in the `laravel` error log file. That said, this problem is likely because you need to wrap all your `routes` that use forms/tokens/auth etc in the `web` [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#route-groups).

Comment: The version that I am using for Laravel is 5.1.31